# Binary words with prescribed numbers of adjacent subpairs

Tags: combinatorics, formal-languages, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose $w:= a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$ is a binary word, i.e. $a_i \in \{0,1\}$ for all $1\le i \le n$. Let $$\sigma(w) = (\text{# subwords } 00, \text{# subwords } 01, \text{# subwords } 10,\text{# subwords } 11)$$
For example, we have $\sigma(01101110101) = (0,4,3,3)$. Note that the entries of $\sigma(w)$ should always add up to $n-1$.

We say a binary word $w$ is *$\sigma$-determined* if $\sigma(v) = \sigma(w)$ implies $v=w$.

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of length $n$ $\sigma$-determined words. How can we calculate $f(n)$? Numerically, we seem to have $f(2n) = f(2n+1) = 4n+2$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Your numerical conjecture seems to say that the only $\sigma$-determined words are those of the forms $00\cdots 0 11\cdots 1$ and $11\cdots 1 00\cdots 0$ and $0101\cdots 01$ (when the length is even) and $1010\cdots 10$ (when the length is odd). This shouldn't be too hard to check.

Comment: Okay, I have an idea. Let's say that a word is *antipalindromic* if reversing it yields the same result as flipping all bits (i.e., replacing each letter $a_i$ by $1-a_i$). Now, if a $\sigma$-determined binary word $w$ contains any nonempty antipalindromic factor that does not abut on one of the ends of the word, then the letter immediately preceding this factor must be distinct from the letter immediately following it (because otherwise, it is easy to see that reversing this factor would give a different binary word with the same $\sigma$, contradicting ...

Comment: ... the "$\sigma$-determined" condition), and therefore this factor must be the central part of a slightly longer antipalindromic factor. Thus, by induction, we see that if our $\sigma$-determined word has any factor of the form $01$ or $10$, then this factor must be the central part of an antipalindromic factor that abuts to an end of the word. This still doesn't pin the word down, but sounds useful.

Comment: Then again, I might well be overthinking the problem. It might be easier to show that if $\left(a,b,c,d\right)$ is a quadruple of nonnegative integers summing up to $n-1$ and satisfying $b \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$ and $a + d \neq 0$, then the fiber $\sigma^{-1}\left(a,b,c,d\right)$ cannot contain exactly $1$ element. This sound straightforward but annoying.

Comment: Oh, I see. Write your binary word in the form $0^{m_1} 1^{n_1} 0^{m_2} 1^{n_2} \cdots$ with all $m_i$ positive. If there are at least two $m_k$'s, and at least one of them is $>1$, then we can easily find a different binary word with the same $\sigma$ by subtracting $1$ from one of the $m_k$'s and adding it onto another. The same argument works if there are at least two $n_k$'s, and at least one of them is $>1$. The cases we are left with are easy to enumerate.

Comment: PS. Please read "even" for "odd" in my very first comment.